# open pdf files in Google Chrome and Opera instead of saving them on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: google-chrome, opera

I use three browsers on my Ubuntu machine: Firefox (67.0.4), Google Chrome (75.0.3770.100), and Opera (60.0.3255.9). If I click on the link to a pdf file in Firefox, then the file will be opened immediately, this is what I want. But neither Chrome nor Opera are able to open pdf file directly, they always ask where to save the file. I have already set the appropriate options (e.g. as described here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213030?hl=en), but nothing helps. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

BR, Udo